# recursive function in C (2 subarrays)

Tags: c, recursion, integer, partitioning, knapsack-problem

We have a code in a class that goes like this:

```
int SubsetSum(int arr[], int idx, int n, int S)
{
    if (S == 0)
        return 1; // This is stopping condition #1.

    if (S < 0 || n == 0)
        return 0; // This is stopping condition #2.

￼    return SubsetSum(arr, idx + 1, n - 1, S - arr[idx])
        || SubsetSum(arr, idx + 1, n - 1, S);
}
```

This code returns 1 if the array can be divided into two subarrays with equal sum (which is the sum of the array/2). I want to expand this function so that it will return two arrays with the numbers.

For input of `1,2,2,3,0` it should return: 
arr1: 2,2
arr2: 3,1

How can I do that? I can't use loops, only recursive functions.

Comment: You don't mention the two conditions, but are the arrays zero-terminated? I. e., can there be nonzero values only in the array?

Comment: yea you can assume the numbers to be entered to the original array are 0 or bigger

Comment: I am not interested in if they can be nonnegative. I'd like to know of they can be 0.

Comment: By the way, what are the `idx`, `n` and `S` variables?

Comment: n is the size of the array ans S is the sum of the whole array.
idx is the the index of the original array to be examined. at first it is 0.

Comment: this is actually a function to be used in a bigger function. ill explain my ultimate goal,maybe it will.help a little. the main function gets only the array and its length. i want to print the two subarrays that their sum is equal, the order does not matter. i am to use only the main function and this function,all recursive

Comment: and this function can get more variables. like 2 more arrays..

Answer (score 1):

Your precondition is not correct: You wrote

> This code returns 1 if the array can be divided into two subarrays with equal sum.

This is not true.  Test with

```
int main() {
   int a[5];
   a[0] = 1; a[1] = 0; a[2] = 0; a[3] = 0; a[4] = 0;

   int const r1 = SubsetSum(a, 0, 5, 1);
   printf("%d\n", r1);

   return 0;
}
```

This returns '1' - even if it cannot be divided into subarrays with equal sum.

Please think about your code and describe exactly what you want.

Comment: yes you are right. u can assune the sum of the array can be divided by 2. i check it on the main function